# Adaptive trigger in nested page not firing after page navigation

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a custom user control that contains a SplitView with a VisualStateManager. Every other page is nested in that control, so that the splitview is shared between all pages, like so:

PageFrame.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactOverlay" />
                    <Setter Target="SplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="False" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="SplitView.DisplayMode" Value="CompactInline" />
                    <Setter Target="SplitView.IsPaneOpen" Value="True" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <SplitView>
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!-- Buttons not relevant for example -->
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <ContentPresenter 
                    Margin="12, 0, 12, 12"
                    Content="{Binding PageContent, ElementName=pageFrame}" />
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

Now, on my main page I have another VisualStateManager, like so:

MainPage.xaml

```
<controls:PageFrame>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Small">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Red"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Green"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <controls:PageFrame.PageContent>
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
           <!-- page content -->
        </Grid>
    </controls:PageFrame.PageContent>
</controls:PageFrame>
```

This VisualStateManager resizes and repositions elements as you would expect (I have excluded he exact implementation here for the sake of brevity), and **it works**. However, whenever I navigate forward or backwards the VSM defaults to **no state, the background of the StoryPanel is white**. As soon as one of the borders is crossed for the first time (i.e. 720/1024) everything starts working perfectly again.

Notice also that everything works perfectly if I remove the PageFrame control from around the content.

Question: Why aren't the correct states triggered on MainPage.xaml after navigation?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to reproduce your issue, but I can not find where is the element "StoryPanel" is defined in your code.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for taking the time. This issue is still very relevant to me. I have updated the question so that the code example makes sense (StoryPanel was basically just the main grid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background will keep white when I resizing the window by using the code your post.

At my side, it will work when I putting the VisualStateManager to root grid.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Small">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Red"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"/>
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="ContentPanel.Background" Value="Green"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <controls:PageFrame>
        <controls:PageFrame.PageContent>
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                <!-- page content -->
            </Grid>
        </controls:PageFrame.PageContent>
    </controls:PageFrame>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake! Thank you, though! :)